# Define scalaVersion setting for RootProject under git in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

In my project, I want to use some code from GitHub. The dependency is defined in `Build.scala` as follows:

```
object BuildSettings {
  val buildVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  val buildScalaVersion = "2.9.1"
  val buildName = "PageAnalyzer"

  val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq (
    organization := buildOrganization,
    version      := buildVersion,
    scalaVersion := buildScalaVersion,
    name         := buildName
  )
}

object PageAnalyzerBuild extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project (
     "root",
     file ("."),
     settings = BuildSettings.buildSettings
  ) dependsOn (depProject)

  val depProject = RootProject(uri("git://github.com/me/some.git"))
}
```

For some reasons, I have to build the root project with Scala **2.9.x**. In SBT **0.13**, the `depProject` will be build with **2.10.x** and the dependency cannot be build. `root` project tries to look for some `some_2.9.1`, but only `some_2.10` is built.

Change `scalaVersion` to 2.10.x works fine. But I have to build the root project with 2.9.x. Is there any way to define `scalaVersion` for `depProject` cloned from git?

Comment: Did you specify `scalaVersion` in the `some.git` project's own build file? I would think that sbt builds `depProject` entirely based on that project's own build file. Perhaps you didn't define `scalaVersion` there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be fine with `scalaVersion in [project-id] := "2.9.0"` where `project-id` is the project identifier from `depProject` or just use `depProject` for `in`. Run `projects` to know the names of available projects and pick the proper one for `in`.

It appears similar to [Setting javac options for SBT dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350739/setting-javac-options-for-sbt-dependencies).